# Is there a way to make a for loop repeat along elements of a list?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop, dplyr

I am new to R. I have a data frame that contains start and end values for 45 types of items, and I used dplyr to subset that data into 45 separate data frames. I have written a for loop that outputs a sequence from start to end for each row of the data frame. I would like to use this for loop on all data frames without having to copy and paste the code 45 times and tailor it to the name of each data frame. See below for an example:

```
A_list <- list()
B_list <- list()
C_list <- list()

dfA <- data.frame(name = c("A", "A"), start = c(1, 3),  end = c(6,  5)) 
dfB <- data.frame(name = c("B", "B"), start = c(2, 1),  end = c(7,  8)) 
dfC <- data.frame(name = c("C", "C"), start = c(1, 2),  end = c(4,  7)) 

for(i in seq_along(dfA$start)) { 
  output <- seq.int(dfA$start[i], dfA$end[i]) 
  A_list[[i]] <- output 
}
```

I tried making a list of names of each data frame and then referring to it in the for loop, but this didn't work.

```
list_df_names <-  list(dfA, dfB, dfC)
seq.int(list_df_names[1:3]$start[i], list_df_names[1:3]$end[i])
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: A good way to get to the list of dataframes, which Akrun uses in their answer, is to use `split`: `list_df_names <- split(x = original_df, f = original_df$name)`

Comment: Overall, though, this feels like a pretty unusual pattern for R. Can you help us understand the broader picture of what you're trying to do, in case there's a more idiomatic way to get there?

Comment: It would be easier if you could do this before splitting the data into list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop of list of datasets, then create the sequence between the 'start', 'end' columns with `Map` to have a `list` of `list`s.  If needed to create separate objects (not recommended), use `list2env` after setting the `names` of the nested `list` with the preferred object names

```
out <- lapply(list_df_names, function(x) Map(seq.int, x$start, x$end))
names(out) <- paste0(c('A', 'B', 'C'), "_list")
list2env(out, .GlobalEnv)
```

-output

```
A_list
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

#[[2]]
#[1] 3 4 5

B_list
#[[1]]
#[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7

#[[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

C_list
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3 4

#[[2]]
#[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7
```